# Best practise to access value of variable across multiple actions in a controller

Tags: controller

Team,
             I have a controller class with different action methods and I need to share a class level value across different actions, what is the ideal approach view bag, session, as for every request a new instance of controller is created and class level variable becomes null so looking for best approach.

Regards
HSR.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the value across requests then you could add it as a property to each of your datamodels, using a hidden variable for example. If your data is sensitive however, you will probably want to use session.